# How Does Forced Movement Work With Corners?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

How does forced movement (in this specific case, a push) interact with corners? I have a situation that is as follows:

[image]

A uses a power that has a push 1. By how I'm interpreting the rules, B cannot be pushed anywhere - to get to D1, he'd have to move 2 squares (D2, then D1) in the same way as if he were trying to walk around the corner normally. Since a push to D2 would leave him no further than when he started, the push doesn't work.

Is this the right line of thinking, or do the rules allow for a diagonal push in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You cannot push a creature when there is an obstacle in the way.**

From DDI:

> Corners: When an obstacle fills a square, you can’t move diagonally
>   across the corner of that square.

and

> a target cannot be forced through blocking terrain.

Comment: Something that makes my players happier about this rule is that I allow them to do damage by slamming the target into the obstacle (usually 1d6 per lost square of forced movement). Likewise, enemies can do it to the players, and powerful pushes can actually damage or destroy terrain. Getting some damage out of it keeps it from feeling like a waste to use push powers in these situations.

Comment: @thatgirldm: This way of bull rushing takes the Dungeoncrasher Alternative Class Feature (Dungeonscape, p.10) for Fighters.